# How does RDP client on Linux work, such as widgets rendering?

Tags: windows, gtk, qt, rdp, remmina

I am curious how the widget rendering is implemented in a Linux RDP client, such as `Remmina`, on a high level. If RDP protocol transmit semantics as much as possible rather than bitmaps, then the client side needs to translate the windows widgets API (the equivalent of GTK/Qt) calls into Linux native calls such as GTK/Qt calls. For example, draw a window frame with minimize/maximize buttons, etc. Is that how it's done in practice?